# Layout for 7" tablets not detected

Tags: android, android-layout

I have /layout for normal screen size, /layout-sw600dp for 7" Tablets and 10" tablets.

7" and 10" should be look the same. The app is working good for normal screens and 10" screens but it is not giving me the right layout for 7" screens.

It is supposed to show a master-detail layout for tablet screens only.

XML file for 10" & 7" screens :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp" android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle" tools:context=".artistListActivity">

    <!--
    This layout is a two-pane layout for the artists
    master/detail flow.

    -->

    <fragment android:id="@+id/artist_list"
        android:name="com.example.amr.spotifystreamer.MainActivityFragment" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1.70"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/artist_detail_container" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="2.74" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.amr.spotifystreamer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import kaaes.spotify.webapi.android.models.Artist;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View detailView = findViewById(R.id.artist_detail_container);
        MainActivityFragment.mTwoPane = detailView!=null &&
                detailView.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.nowplaying){{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), MediaPlayer.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(intent);
        }}
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're an android nanodegree student from udacity, which am I too. So, if your 7 inch and 10 inch layout are the same, you don't need to use sw720dp since sw600dp cover that as well.

Actually, sw means smallest width, so if your 7" tablet is a cheap one with resolution 480 x 800, it will not fall into sw600dp group. Normal 7" tablets are assumed to have a resolution of at least 600 x 1240. Try reducing the smallest width number and check if the layout changes on your 7" tablet, i.e. try starting with sw480dp, and so on.

Comment: Yes I am a nano degree student :D ..At first I only has /layout-xlarge and it also worked for 10" only ..any suggestions ?

Comment: layout-xlarge is for android version below android 3.2. If your minimum sdk is greater than 13, you don't need to include that. I've editted the answer to include more information.